# PendingIntent from second action overwrites the first action and the contentIntent for Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

### The code:

```
int id = 0;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_on_the_move_gps_title))
  .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_on_the_move_text));

builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.notification_on_the_move_gps_big_text)));

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

Intent turnOffIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
turnOffIntent.putExtra(MainApp.KEY_TURN_OFF_NOTIFICATION_ID, id);

TaskStackBuilder mainBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
mainBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
mainBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
PendingIntent mainPendingIntent = mainBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(mainPendingIntent);

TaskStackBuilder turnOffBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
turnOffBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
turnOffBuilder.addNextIntent(turnOffIntent);
PendingIntent turnOffPendingIntent = turnOffBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
  .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
  .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification, "Open", mainPendingIntent)
  .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification_off, "Turn off", turnOffPendingIntent);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(id, builder.build());
```

### The problem:

Clicking on the unexpanded or expanded notification body or on the Open action button always transfers the intent with (KEY_TURN_OFF_NOTIFICATION_ID) extra.

I've tried ditching the TaskStackBuilder and creating `PendingIntent`s simply:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent piMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

Intent turnOffIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
turnOffIntent.putExtra(MainApp.KEY_TURN_OFF_NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
PendingIntent piTurnOff = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, turnOffIntent, 0);
```

but, to same effect :(

If I ommit `setContentIntent()`, naturally, tapping on the notification body does nothing.

If I set `setContentIntent()` *after* setting actions, then the extra is never received in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

So you have to make those intents different as in `Intent.filterEquals` method:

> That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

As a side note, I had the same problem while working on the download notifications of firefox for android [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/NotificationHelper.java#192)

Comment: Adding action to each to differentiate them made the difference. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: In my opinion this is a design flaw and surely not a "mistake" android developers make.

Comment: i jammed some random string in `setType()` and it worked fine, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Although i achieved it by setting SetType()

Comment: Set Type also worked for me, used it on the intent passed to the pending intent.

Answer (score 5):

Hence [`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) flag will just overwrite the extras if you are creating new intent where only the extras change.

Try adding distinct

- action like `intent.setAction("DISTINCT.ACTION.HERE")` or
- category like `intent.addCategory("DISTINCT.CATEGORY.HERE")`

for each intents.

cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to differentiate between the two requests is to set a unique `requestCode` for each one.

Taking the above code as an example, assign unique `requestCode`s like so:

```
int mainRequestCode = 1;
int turnOffRequestCode = 2;

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent piMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mainRequestCode, mainIntent, 0);

Intent turnOffIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
turnOffIntent.putExtra(MainApp.KEY_TURN_OFF_NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
PendingIntent piTurnOff = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, turnOffRequestCode, turnOffIntent, 0);
```